# Android Search in other languages based on pronunciation

Tags: android, full-text-search, android-contacts

I have been struggling with a problem from past few days.

We have to implement a search feature that must be able to search the content that is written in other languages but searched in English pronunciation. For example if there is a content like below

Hello is translated as 你好 in Chinese, Pronounced as Nǐ hǎo, so if the user types Nǐ hǎo in the search field 你好 should be in the search results.

I found that contacts app is doing something similar for which I have uploaded a screenshot here. I thought that we have to go with some Transliteration kind of idea, but it won't work here as the content is dynamic. So I wanted to know what might be a simpler way to achieve this.

I am not sure on where to start with this issue. Can anyone please point me to a link that would help me with this?

Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Contacts app isn't doing transliteration in real-time when you search for a word.

It stored the [phonetic-name](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.html#PHONETIC_GIVEN_NAME) of a contact into the contact details, and searches for the regular display-name as well as the phonetic field.

I think you need something else, that will happen in real-time

There was a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36916288) for this to be added to Android, but it was rejected.

Comment: How can I save phonetic name of my required content? In above screen shot I did not add any phonetic name for the displayed name

Comment: the contacts framework will add the phonetic name automatically if it detects a certain language of the contact name (chinese, indic), I don't think you can do the same in your app, you'll have to add some transliteration library to your app